# where to implement counter of consecutive visits?

Tags: php, javascript, sql

so first of all i checked and researched this question in stackoverflow and google but there no similar question.

i checked [Count number of consecutive visits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041779/count-number-of-consecutive-visits) and [SQL Query: Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298140/sql-query-visited-the-site-each-day-for-30-consecutive-days) but it doesn't help.

so my question is where to implement this action of testing if a user has visited the site for  a consecutive x time, in the links that i put there they check in server side, but i think it's not very optimised because each time the user visits the website a query is triggered to check if todays date is equal or higher than `LastVisit` date.

in my application i already do query every time the user loads a page to retrieve his information but if i add an

```
update userInfo 
set DaysConsecutivelyVisited=DaysConsecutivelyVisited+1
when DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),LastVisit)=1
```

then i'll have two queries every time the user loads the page, so i tought maybe it's better if i do this in client side rather than in server side. I'll put an attribute or hidden span in the document

```
<body data-lastvisit="2012-03-25" >
```

and in the javascript i'll do the analysis and if the `$("data-lastvisit")` is equal to yesterday i'll send an ajax reqeuest to update the `DaysConsecutivelyVisited`

what do you think, is it a good idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a parameter to compare to.. which is - unfortunately - always the data inside your database table. The only thing you can do is to retrieve the userinfo on pageload, which most likely includes a field `last_visited`. If the date is not equal to todays date, registered it.

Furthermore, I'd say create a field `consecutive_visits` and reset to 0 in case the date's difference is larger than a day and increment it in case there's a day or less difference. This way you'd always have the amount of consecutive visits in the userobject after fetching it on pageload.

I absolutely do not see any need for an ajax request in this case. It's just a compare of the current user data with a Date() instance or timestamp. All calculating can be done serverside and there's only need for an extra MySQL query in case the values are different.